# Minimal MRTK Project with Hand Tracking Scenes running in Holographic Remoting

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I’ve been trying to get the example hand tracking scenes to run with holographic remoting with MRTK 2.5.1, Unity 2019.4.13f, XR SDK, a USB connection and the Hololens 2 but haven’t been completely successful. Does anybody have a minimal project setup where the example handtracking scenes run in holographic remoting without crashing?

Answer (score 0):

If HoloLens 2 hand joints or eye-tracking isn’t working over remoting, there are a few common points of potential issues. It is recommended you go through the set-up steps to enable additional HL2 features over remoting. Please take a look at our guide and see if your setup matches those steps:[Debugging HoloLens 2 remoting via Unity package import](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Tools/HolographicRemoting.html#debugging-hololens-2-remoting-via-unity-package-import)

Comment: I actually got the hand tracking to work but the app crashes when using holographic remoting after a while. A problem that doesn't occur when I deploy the app.

Comment: Could you double-check that you have updated the latest HoloLens 2 build and Holographic Remoting Software so that we can avoid some known issue, and the current recommendation is to use Windows Holographic 20H2, more information please see:[HoloLens 2 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes). If still not work, please report this issue by Feedback Hub. For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has issues following the instructions on https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Tools/HolographicRemoting.html#xr-sdk-setup-instructions here is a
[Minimal Project with Holographic Remoting and XR SDK](https://github.com/isaakhanimann/holographic-remoting-xr-sdk-minimal-project)
The sample scene runs with holographic remoting but not the Example Hand Tracking Scenes from MRTK.